# How to optimize this MySQL query used for fetching images with similar colors to another image?

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have to fetch items (images) that have similar colors to another one. I saved into the database 5 predominat colors, in hex format, for every image. Basically what I do right now is:

1. Get the 5 predominant colors from the image used to search for other images with similar colors.
2. Check if every other images' colors match one of those 5 colors.
3. Show only images with at least 1 matched color.
4. Order the results by number of colors matched and by image's ID.

This is the "colors" table, where I save all the colors and their IDs:

[image]

- Indexes:

[image]

This is the "colors_rel" table, where I add records for linking colors with items' IDs:

[image]

- Indexes:

[image]

I won't paste here my "items" table because it won't be used by the query we're going to consider.

Finally this is an example query that I'm using:

[image]

This is the result of the EXPLAIN:

[image]

One thing that it's probably interesting is that all the hex values are like this: x0x0x0, the 2nd, 4th and 6th characters are always = 0;

I run everything on a quad core machine with 16gb of ram and the query runs in an average time of 0.150s. These are some of the values setted by my.cnf:

```
key_buffer_size=256M
sort_buffer_size=16M
query_cache_size=32M
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=2M
tmp_table_size=512MB
max_heap_table_size=512MB
read_buffer_size=262144
```

I hope you guys know a better way to perform this query. This is the main bottleneck of my website. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I got no other answers I post what I was able to achieve:

- I changed the data type of the ID column of the colors table from mediumint(8) to smallint(5), this should give me a bit smaller indexes, but the performance improvement was very tiny.
- I tried to store only the first, third and fifth char of the hex colors, since the others were always 0. Again the same benefits as the previous point.
- The only real solution that I've found is to create another table where basically store the number of colors matched from every item to every other item. But with some calculus I found that this table will currently need around 4 **billions** records, and I chose to wait 100ms for every time that query is executed instead of dealing with a so huge table.

So right now the solution found was: there's no easy solution to this problem that it's worthing the time, if anyone have a better solution I'll be happy to listen to it.